# Get response from server C#

Tags: c#, forms, webbrowser-control

I'm trying to submit a from using c# to a website and am trying to get the response from the server as a message box after the data is sent. the website does redirect to another page to show an output.

What happens so far is the data is not submitted until I click OK on the message box that is displaying the data before it is send not after.

```
                WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser();
                string target = "http://www.awebsite.com";

                browser.Navigate(target);
                browser.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(XYZ);

            }
        }
        private void XYZ(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e) // fail was here.

        {

            WebBrowser b = (WebBrowser)sender;
            string text = richTextBox1.Text.ToString();
            if (text == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("the messgae was empty");
                    }

            b.Document.GetElementById("idmsg").InnerText = richTextBox1.Text.ToUpper().ToString();
            b.Document.GetElementById("idpassw").InnerText = ".....";
            b.Document.GetElementById("idpagers").InnerText = id;
            b.Document.GetElementById("Send").InvokeMember("click");
            // allow server response time
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
            string output = b.Document.Body.OuterText.ToString();
            MessageBox.Show(output);
         }
```

I'v also tried adding another `Document complete with the //allow server response time code` but again did'nt send till OK was pressed.

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -2):

You do it totally wrong. Never rely on the`.Sleep(...)`. C# provides rich enough async environment, namely `Task DoAsync(...)` which is to be used somewhat like `await DoAsync()`. This guarantees that no code going below the `DoAsync()` would ever be executed unless the async operation either completed successfully, either failed with error. As such, by the time you'll get to the last `MessageBox.Show(...)`, all the data would be there, displayed properly as expected.

Comment: @shaggs I guess it's your time to google things; async/await's are well-known things, you would easily find thousands of examples.

Comment: @shaggs the only feature async/await adds to your code is... asynchrony. So, the result of the operation depends upon underlying code executed via async/await API: it may or may not redirect.

Comment: This won't resolve the redirect issue.. What I need is another wait till page load with result from redirect